# How to Upload Custom Playlist Cover using Python API to Spotify Playlist

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm working on a project that requires me to make multiple playlists all with Custom Playlist Art. I would like to be able to do this in the script instead of manually doing it.

I have tried looking at the documentation but there is not much when it has not been much help to me. I have the following code:

I am not using the spotipy currently, and would like to avoid it if possible.

```
image_path = '/local/path/to/albumCover/Album_Cover.jpg'
endpoint_url = f"https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}/images"
response = requests.put(url = endpoint_url,  data = image_path, headers={"Content-Type":"image/jpeg",
                        "Authorization":"Bearer " + token})

print(response.json())
```

I am getting the following response code:

```
{'error': {'status': 400, 'message': 'Bad request.'}}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.